# How to reduce Firestore document reads when we have many users reading the same collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Here's our problem:**

We are building an employee directory. Each employee in an organisation will be able to search and view all other employees in the same organisation.

We are currently considering two different approaches to how we store and manage employees:

**Approach A**

Maintain a subcollection of employees under each organisation. In this model, each employee will be its own document.

The benefit of this approach is that we get leverage all of the features that come with subcollections in firestore. We can easily add, update, and delete employees, and there are no real changes that we would need to be made as the collection grows.

The main issue with this approach is that we're going to have a ton of reads. If we take a company with 1,000 employees, and assume that each employee visits the directory 5 times a day, we're looking at `1,000 * 5 * 1,000 = 5,000,000 reads/day`. This seems like far too many reads for a set of resources that are only going to change a few times a day (assuming employee churn).

The obvious solution to this problem seems to be caching the employees, but I'm not too sure how we can do that without using a cloud function to fetch the employees?

**Approach B**

Maintain an array or employees on each organisation document. In this model, all employees will exist within the organisation document.

The benefit of this approach is that we only need a single document read to fetch all employees. This means fetching the collection will be a lot faster and cheaper.

The main issue with this approach is that we're going to have to split up the organisation document as the size of the employee array grows. This shouldn't be too much of an issue until there are > 5k employees, but it still seems quite messy. Once the array is split it up, we would also need to manage which chunk each employee belongs to, overcomplicating updates.

Speaking of updates, this approach also complicates employee updates, as each time an employee is updated, the entire array will have to be rewritten.

Is there another better approach to this problem, or am I overlooking some simple solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach B will not scale, and you will have trouble in the future with it.  It's not recommended.  Also, you will add complexity in terms of security rules to protect that document, and you could also run into the rate limit for document writes under load.  I do not recommend this.

Approach A is the logical choice. It's cleaner and more sensical.  And 5 million reads is only $3, which is a paltry sum for a company that has 1000 employees.  That's much less than the development effort to implement B correctly.  If you really need to cut that cost down, then just don't allow everyone to load all over user's documents in one go.  Use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) instead if users need to browse the list.